# How to count the number of observations above a threshold in a dataframe using loop

Tags: r, loops

I have a dataframe S1
I would like to know (by keeping the header of S1) how many values are above 50
here is my code:

```
ncols <- length(S1)
compliance <- setNames(numeric(ncol(S1)), names(S1))
for (i in 1:ncols) {
    i1 <- S1[[i]]>50
    compliance[i] <- sum(i1)}
```

for some reason I get NA values. Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

No loop required, we can use either `sapply` or even more-efficiently `colSums`.

```r
compliance <- colSums(S1 > 50)
compliance <- sapply(S1, function(z) sum(z > 50))
```

or better yet, we can use `colSums`:

```r
colSums(mtcars > 50)
#  mpg  cyl disp   hp drat   wt qsec   vs   am gear carb 
#    0    0   32   32    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 
sapply(mtcars, function(z) sum(z > 50))
#  mpg  cyl disp   hp drat   wt qsec   vs   am gear carb 
#    0    0   32   32    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. In every column I have NA values of different frequencies. Is it possible that it messes up this? Even with colSums(S1 > 50) I get NA values everywhere, but it seesm to work with colSums(na.omit(S1) > 50)

Comment: `na.rm=TRUE` is an available argument for both `sum` and `colSums`

Comment: but if you really would prefer to use `na.omit`, then it can be used in sapply, with `sapply(mtcars, function(z) sum(na.omit(z) > 50))` (it cannot be used in `colSums`).